# Synchronize Parent and Child to read from a file without semaphores

Tags: c++, linux, process, pipe, fork

In Pipes

(0)How to prevent parent from overwriting the data if child hasn't yet read it
*****In child process*****

(1)how would child know that new data in pipe has arrived and should be read

(2)how would child know that it is not rereading the same line from pipe 

(3)what would be the terminating condition for child after reading all data sent by parent from pipe.

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Post it as (formatted) text into the question. Otherwise it makes it hard for others to copy it to try or reference in a comment/answer. And many people view SO on mobile devices which seperate code images also don't play nice with.

Comment: And when you post your code please format properly. In particular, use correct and consistent indenting.

Comment: Thanks @kaylum , I am new here

Comment: (0) That's done automatically by the pipe. It won't overwrite unread data (1) `read` blocks until data is available. Or use `select`. (2) Done automatically by pipe. It only allows data to be read once. (3) `read` returns 0 on EOF.

Comment: (1)If I do it in while(true) it repeats the data in "cout". It must show data read only once
"(2) Done automatically by pipe. It only allows data to be read once."
I tried and the same line "Echo!!!" was being printed indefinitely, I had to kill the process manually

Comment: It doesn't mean that the pipe is returning the same data. It means your code has other bugs and that you've jumped to the wrong conclusion! Always check the return value of each function call. In this case, check the `read` return value. In the "printed indefinitely" case I'll bet you'll find the `read` is failing so you are just printing the previous old data continuously!

Comment: while(read(fd[0],receiver,sizeof(receiver)) != 0)  {  
        cout<<receiver<<endl;
 }
Doing this resulted in showing "Hello" and the child terminated. On parent side all data was sent successfully in pipe though.

Comment: Putting parent to sleep for a few seconds WORKED.
is there any other better method you want to share will be highly appreciated.
"read returns 0 on EOF." This line did the magic.
Thanks @kaylum

Answer (score 0):

In Pipes
(0)How to prevent parent from overwriting the data if child hasn't yet read it
In child process   **ANSWER: In Pipes, Sender Can Overwrite the Data, in this case I used Sleep to prevent parent from doing that, meanwhile child read the data sent by parent**
(1)how would child know that new data in pipe has arrived and should be read
**ANSWER: Child/Receiver would "know" when new data arrives,would not collect the data till then**
(2)how would child know that it is not rereading the same line from pipe
**ANSWER: Happens Automagically, read() NEVER reads the data(that has been read) AGAIN**
(3)what would be the terminating condition for child after reading all data sent by parent from pipe.
**Answer:read() returns 0 on EOF** 

***Thanks to Kaylum for helping***  (in the comments)